# Parse Cast from Int to String Doesnt work

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a Parse column with type `Int` and I cant make use of it. Cast doesnt work. How Can I assign this to a Label.text?

**My Code:**

```
Cell.MyLabel.text = restaurant["name"] as! String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the String constructor:

```
if let name = restaurant["name"] {
    Cell.MyLabel.text = String(name)
}
```